# De-normalizing data in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following schema that I read from csv:

```
val PersonSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("PersonID",StringType,true), StructField("Name",StringType,true)))
val AddressSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("PersonID",StringType,true), StructField("StreetNumber",StringType,true), StructField("StreetName",StringType,true)))
```

One person can have multiple addresses and is related through PersonID.

Can someone help transform the records to a PersonAddress records as in the following case class definition?

```
case class Address(StreetNumber:String, StreetName:String)
case class PersonAddress(PersonID:String, Name:String, Addresses:Array[Address])
```

I have tried the following but it is giving exception in the last step:

```
val results = personData.join(addressData, Seq("PersonID"), "left_outer").groupBy("PersonID","Name").agg(collect_list(struct("StreetNumber","StreetName")) as "Addresses")
val personAddresses = results .map(data => PersonAddress(data.getAs("PersonID"),data.getAs("Name"),data.getAs("Addresses")))
personAddresses.show
```

Gives an error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$Address

Comment: What's the type of `data.getAs("Addresses")`? Isn't it a list of structs? You should `map` over it too which I think for-comprehension would make pretty.

Comment: How do I do that? When I tried the following it complains that "value map is not a member of Nothing"


val personAddresses = results .map(data => PersonAddress(data.getAs("PersonID"),data.getAs("Name"),data.getAs("Addresses").map(df => Address(df.getAs("StreetNumber"), df.getAs("StreetName"))))

Comment: `data.getAs[Addresses]("Addresses")`?

Comment: You mean like this?                 

val personAddresses = results .map(data => PersonAddress(data.getAs("PersonID"),data.getAs("Name"),data‌​.getAs[Array[Address]]("Addresses")))

I am getting the following error:  

java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [L$line69.$read$$iw$$iw$Address;

Comment: @SYL Did the answer help you solve the problem? If not, what problems/errors occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution in this situtation would be to use an `UDF`. First, collect the street numbers and names as two separate lists, then use the `UDF` to convert everything into a dataframe of `PersonAddress`.

```
val convertToCase = udf((id: String, name: String, streetName: Seq[String], streetNumber: Seq[String]) => {
  val addresses = streetNumber.zip(streetName) 
  PersonAddress(id, name, addresses.map(t => Address(t._1, t._2)).toArray)
})

val results = personData.join(addressData, Seq("PersonID"), "left_outer")
  .groupBy("PersonID","Name")
  .agg(collect_list($"StreetNumber").as("StreetNumbers"), 
       collect_list($"StreetName").as("StreetNames"))
val personAddresses = results.select(convertToCase($"PersonID", $"Name", $"StreetNumbers", $"StreetNames").as("Person"))
```

This will give you a schema as below.

```
root
 |-- Person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- PersonID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Addresses: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- StreetNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- StreetName: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How does this take advantage of the distributed computation nature of spark? Or how can we optimized this to take advantage of this for distributed parallel processing in spark?

Comment: @SYL Spark will take care of that for you automatically as long as you run it on a cluster and not locally.